# nextjs 404 page loading optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js project where I use the default 404 page.
But If I go to the network tab of the browser I can see a lot of things loading for this 404 page.

[image]

My _document.tsx file is like this

```
  <Html className="html" color-theme="default">
                <Head>
                    <meta name="app-version" content={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_VERSION} />
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
                    <script
                        crossOrigin="anonymous"
                        src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.PluralRules%2CIntl.Locale%2CIntl.PluralRules.~locale.en%2CIntl.PluralRules.~locale.sv%2CResizeObserver%2CObject.fromEntries"
                    ></script>
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
```

So the favicon and the polyfill.min.js loading make sense but I am not sure why other files loading for this simple 404 page. especially CSS files and font files.

Then I created a brand new project and try to load the 404 page still I can see a bunch of script files loading. Why is this happening in nextjs? Is there a way to load a minimum of 404 page with just only HTML and css?
[image]

Comment: Run in production mode and see, Dev mode will have other dependencies also like HMR, etc...

Comment: @RahulSharma I checked the prod build still same

Comment: It'll depend on how Next.js bundles the files in your app, but essentially those are all needed by the framework to render the 404 page. If you want to optimise that page, then I'd recommend you start by optimising `_app` as it has the largest size and is common to all pages.